# In my example, can I remove the word--"that"?

Tags: sentence

This suggests that the current MLDA is not effective. However, the estimates in this paper challenge that claim and show that the effects of the current MLDA is statistically significant in all cases we observe.

This suggests that the current MLDA is not effective. However, the estimates in this paper challenge that claim and show that the effects of the current MLDA is statistically significant in all cases **that** we observe.

Comment: *Effects...is* is likely to be more noticeable than a possibly otiose *that*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can remove that in the sentence and not significantly change the meaning.

That said, I believe it sounds better with *that* left in place. But, that is merely a matter of style.